# Enabling Redirection in Kamailio SIP Server

Tags: sip, proxy-server, sip-server, kamailio

How can we enable redirection in Kamilio SIP Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about the "User Agent Client redirection", there is a module in kamailio.
It has the following functionality: UAC REDIRECT - module enhance Kamailio with the functionality of being able to handle (interpret, filter, log and follow) redirect responses ( 3xx replies class). Please find the usage examples and description on the official website https://kamailio.org/docs/modules/3.3.x/modules_k/uac_redirect.html